# Portrait and landscape image sizes for App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm taking screenshot images to send to App Store.

I have [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html), but I couldn't understand in this guide that why there are both the portrait and landscape sizes listed; do I have to send both the portrait and landscape sizes?

Comment: No, you can do either or both. If you had a game that only worked in landscape, for example, you'd probably only show landscape screenshots.

Comment: Okey, I want to approve this, if you write this as a reply.